# Crashes when pasting excel range as table format in powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have tried to copy a excel range and paste as table format in powerpoint using excel vba. It pasting the range but when I resize the table the Powerpoint application is crashing.

Comment: You should do all your resize and stuff in Power point VBA not from excel modules. Its like your (excel)code trying to alter the properties of powerpoint. You can do it provided you write proper code in establishing a interface.

Comment: I have found writing from Excel to Powerpoint works better than the reverse. (i.e. no crashes) What I have done is create the table first in PowerPoint as a master slide so I can preset the table rows and columns sizes. (This allows you to do things similar to merge cells) Once the table is created you can add new slides and copy the data from excel, one cell at a time to the PowerPoint table. I have used this to transfer Excel data one row at a time to 100+ PPT slides, all in the same layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution helped me to get rid of chrasing powerpoint application. I wrote the table resize function in powerpoint file and executed it.

Thanks alot...